# Including a PHAR file in a PHP Script (PHP5.3 / Debian)

Tags: php, debian, archive, silex, phar

I'm trying to include a PHAR file (PHP Archive) in my PHP script, it works fine on WAMP, but not on my debian server !

My server has PHP5.3 (including PHAR extension natively !), but my script stops when including the PHAR (in fact [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org))

My code (file_exists() works fine):

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/silex.phar';
```

I saw that PHAR is enabled thanks to phpinfo().

However, I tried many things to correct this problem:

- I had `AddType application/x-httpd-php .phar` in my httpd.conf
- Also, I tried to fixe a bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=639268
- I saw this: http://www.shaunfreeman.co.uk/article/A-Phar-problem, but not resolving my prob...

Nothing works... have a solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you think apache would have to do with a filesystem request, but did you check for php or system errors (e.g., security/permissions)?

Comment: Did you try all the things mentioned here? http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#pitfalls

Comment: Thanks all, in fact I tried all but not together ! By setting phar option Off in the php.ini + the suhosin whitelist, it works ! Thanks !

Comment: If all is correct you can then close your question.

Comment: and add your solution as answer.

Answer (score 2):

when you use PHP with the Suhosin patch, you may need to enable the use of phars in the suhosin.ini.

You can add the line to the suhosin.ini

suhosin.executor.include.whitelist = phar

If you don't do so the script will fail silently

This is common on debian and ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Solutions to the most common problems with getting PHAR to work are documented in [the pitfalls section of the Silex documentation](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/phar.html#pitfalls).

Comment: It may need to disable xcache/apc/eaccelerator : phar issues appends in some very specific eaccelerator config.